# Puppeteer creates PDF before all iframes have loaded

Tags: node.js, iframe, puppeteer

I need to create a PDF for a web page that includes around 20 iframes that display some charts. Obviously, I need to wait until all iframes have loaded. For this I tried the following (snippet):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
const page = await browser.newPage()

const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
await page.goto(url)  
await navigationPromise

const pdf = await page.pdf()
await browser.close()
```

My understanding is that the `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` option is supposed to wait until there is no network traffic at all for 500 milliseconds. However, the iframes aren't always displayed, some yes, others no.

I also tried `networkidle2` but no improvement (which is supposed to work for long-running network connections which is not our case).

What other approach could I try to make sure all iframes have been loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `load` and the `networkidle*` events should fire after the frames have been loaded. However, if the frames are attached to the page after the `page.waitForNavigation` is resolved, you might need to specifically listen for your frames to load.

There is the [`framenavigated`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-framenavigated) event, which is "emitted when a frame is navigated to a new url". If you know the number of frames, that you need to listen to, you could simply wait until all frames are loaded like this:

```js
const EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES = 5;
await Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => { // wait until all frames are navigated
        let numberOfLoadedFrames = 0;
        page.on('framenavigated', () => {
            numberOfLoadedFrames += 1;
            if (numberOfLoadedFrames === (EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES + 1)) {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }),
    page.goto('...')
]);
```

The code will listen for the number of `framenavigated` event calls and `resolve` the Promise when the expected number is reached. Keep in mind, that the main frame will also fire the `framenavigated` event once, therefore the `EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES + 1` in my code.

Depending on the complexity of the page, you could also listen to the emitted number of [`frameattached`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-frameattached) events, which will signal how many frames are in the page. That way you could detect automatically how many frames are in the page. However, in this case, you should first wait a few milliseconds to be sure to catch all frames.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher Thanks :D There was actually another answer, that was already accepted but seems to be deleted now...

Comment: May also have to wait for frame network ilde  `await frame.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" });`