# Wait for iframes to load in Puppeteer PDF generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, puppeteer

I am trying to load some iframes during the generation of a PDF using Puppeteer for a Ruby on Rails project. I am using the `puppeteer-ruby` gem for this.

While the PDF gets generated successfully, the iframes are not loaded and therefore do not appear the output file.

The code I am using for the PDF generation is rather basic:

```rb
Puppeteer.launch(headless: true) do |browser|
  page = browser.new_page
  page.content = html(posts)
  page.pdf(
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
      top: '1cm',
      bottom: '1cm',
      left: '1cm',
      right: '1cm'
    },
    print_background: true,
    display_header_footer: true,
    header_template: '',
    footer_template: footer_pagination
  )
end
```

In turn, each post might have something like this:

```html
<iframe
  src="<%= some_path(some_object) %>"
  loading='lazy'
  class='w-100 border-0'>
</iframe>
```

This works properly when visited in a browser but not when rendered by Puppeteer.

How can I tell Puppeteer to wait for those iframes to load before generating the PDF? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

'framenavigated' event will be fired after the content of iframe loaded completely. Probably you can observe the event with Page#on or Page#once.

- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051
- [Puppeteer creates PDF before all iframes have loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776498/puppeteer-creates-pdf-before-all-iframes-have-loaded)